# SonataAdminBundle disable editing only on certain items

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am currently working on a project where Moderation is the requirement.

There are multiple groups of users:

1. Content Creator
2. Content Reviewer
3. Admins

The business requirement is that once CREATOR has submitted items for REVIEW, they should not be able to  edit it anymore.

How can we disable editing on certain items by checking if STATUS of the item is UNDER_REVIEW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way would be to use ACLs, as described in the [Sonata Admin Security docs](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html).

In summary:

- [Integrate with FOSUserBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#acl-and-friendsofsymfony-userbundle), conveniently by using [SonataUserBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/master/doc/reference/installation.html) (I'm sure there are other options for managing users)
- [Configure ACLs in Sonata](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#configuration)
- Set up your Roles as required, and then [create a Custom Voter](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#create-a-custom-voter-or-a-custom-permission-map) which can check the Role of the User, and the state of the object, and vote to grant access only if appropriate, something like this:

*Voter*

```
public function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
{
    //...

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if ($this->supportsAttribute($attribute) && $object instanceof Item) {
            if $attribute == 'EDIT' && ($token->getUser()->hasRole('ROLE_CREATOR') && $object->getStatus() == 'UNDER_REVIEW')
                return self::ACCESS_DENIED;
            }

            if (($token->getUser()->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') {
                return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
            //etc etc
        }
    }

    //...
}
```